# Import string that looks like a list "[0448521958, +61439800915]" from JSON into Python and make it an actual list?

Tags: python, json, list, abstract-syntax-tree

I am extracting a string out of a JSON document using python that is being sent by an app in development. This question is similar to some other questions, but I'm having trouble just using `x = ast.literal_eval('[0448521958, +61439800915]')` due to the plus sign.

I'm trying to get each phone number as a string in a python list x, but I'm just not sure how to do it. I'm getting this error:

```
raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: It's complaining because `0448521958` is an invalid octal constant, which is how `literal_eval()` is trying to interpret it, just like if you typed `>>> 0448521958` into the Python console. You need to text process the input string to extract the two number strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `ast.literal_eval` is trying to interpret the phone numbers as numbers instead of strings. Try this:

```
str = '[0448521958, +61439800915]'
str.strip('[]').split(', ')
```

Result:

```
['0448521958', '+61439800915']
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think this is what I'm looking for. Let me test.

Comment: Yes, this is working, and I don't even need to use `literal_eval` any more.

Answer (score 2):

your problem **is not** just the +

the first number starts with `0` which is an octal number ... it only supports 0-7 ... but the number ends with 8 (and also has other numbers bigger than 8)

but it turns out your problems dont stop there

you can use regex to fix the plus

```
fixed_string = re.sub('\+(\d+)','\\1','[0445521757, +61439800915]')
ast.literal_eval(fixed_string)
```

I dont know what you can do about the octal number problem however

Comment: The leading `+` isn't valid JSON either; the JSON grammar only permits a `-` or digit there.

Answer (score 1):

Technically that string isn't valid JSON. If you want to ignore the +, you could strip it out of the file or string before you evaluate it.  If you want to preserve it, you'll have to enclose the value with quotes.

Comment: I have asked the other developer to try to send with quotes around the numbers. We will see.